# Send MapMyRun data to Runkeeper

Tags: running, technology

I've been using MapMyRun for a few years now, generally it's ok stats wise but is pretty horrible to use. So looking to move all my data from it to Runkeeper, is there a way this can be done?

Ideally it would be great if all the runs I have completed in MapMyRun are replicated in Runkeeper, is that even possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about tech, not sports

Comment: This question is much more suitable for [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @studro Can it be moved to the correct stack rather than closed? It'll likely get more attention here than on some tech stack.

Comment: @TrueDub We have this question which, from my untrained eye, seems to also ask how to transfer data from a running log:  https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-transfer-data-between-online-running-logs. Related [meta discussion](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/380/actuality-problem-of-questions/381).

Comment: @mastermind_ed And I'd have voted to close or transfer that one too if I'd seen it.

Answer (score 3):

I found this - https://www.fitnesssyncer.com/

It worked great, did all my runs separately including all the data and routes!